# How do I find exiisting gitlab project cluster in Pulumi?

Tags: typescript, kubernetes, gitlab, pulumi

> I have connected a Kubernetes cluster in Gitlab as a project cluster
> https://gitlab.com/steinKo/gitlabcicd/-/clusters/142291
> I want to acsess this cluster in Pulumi
> Folow thw dcumentaion can I use Look up an Existing ProjectCluster Resource
> Could I use the API call

```
public static get(name: string, id: Input<ID>, state?: ProjectClusterState, opts?: CustomResourceOptions): ProjectCluster
```

> I wrote

```
import * as gitlab from "@pulumi/gitlab";

const cluster = gitlab.get("gitlabcicd", ???)
```

> Then I get an errormessage : Property get dose not exit
> How do I use get API?
> Where do I find the id?

Comment: Just try to start entering method name char by char and your IDE will help you to choose right method

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the cluster using the following code:

```js
import * as gitlab from "@pulumi/gitlab";

const projectCluster = gitlab.ProjectCluster.get("mycluster", "clusterid");
```

where `mycluster` is the name you're giving it in your Pulumi program and `clusterid` is the ID in GitLab of the cluster.

You can get the ID of the cluster using the GitLab API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_clusters.html

Please note that this will not allow you to make changes to the cluster (as you're not importing it into the Pulumi program), but it will give you information about the cluster itself.

If you wanted to start managing the cluster in your Pulumi program, then you can import it using the CLI by running this command: `pulumi import gitlab:index/projectCluster:ProjectCluster bar projectid:clusterid` which will give you the correct code to copy and paste into your Pulumi program at which point you can start managing it.

Comment: Wher do I find the clusterid in the Gitlab web?

Comment: You can get it using the gitlab API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_clusters.html

Answer (score 0):

Reading the pulumi docs looks like in order to retrieve project the right syntax would be:

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as gitlab from "@pulumi/gitlab";

const example = pulumi.output(gitlab.getProject({
    id: "gitlabcicd",
}, { async: true }));
```

Reference: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/gitlab/getproject/

Comment: Now that I have the Gitlab Project. How do I get the Gitlab project cluster?

Comment: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/gitlab/projectcluster/ - everything is inside the docs. please read them.